# Solving inverse differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

How to solve

$$
\frac{1}{D_{x}^{2}+D_{x}D_{y}-12D_{y}^{2}}(ye^{3x+y}+x^{3})?
$$

I understand that I need to use 
$$
\frac{1}{\varphi(D_{x},D_{y})}(e^{ax+by}.V(x,y))=e^{ax+by}\frac{1}{\varphi(D_{x}+a,D_{y}+b)}V(x,y)
$$
but I don't know how.